# To prove a function is constant throughout some domain.

Tags: complex-analysis

I have some difficulty in providing valid and logical arguments for my proof for the theorem:-
If f'(z)=0 everywhere in a domain D, then f(z) must be constant throughout D.
I know that if differentiation is 0 everywhere in D then the function satisties Cauchy Riemann equations and continuous at everypoint in D.
It means partial derivatives are zero. Can I conclude directly that the function has real and imaginary parts constant everywhere?

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:** Fix a $z_0 \in D$,and consider the following set $$A=\{ z\in D: f(z)=f(z_0)\}$$

Show that $A$ is clopen subset of a **connected** set $D$,hence $A=D$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use the fact $D$ is a domain. A counterexample if not: let $D = \left\{z \in \mathbb{C} \mid \lvert z \rvert < 1 \textrm{ or }\lvert z \rvert > 2\right\}$ and
$$f(z) = \begin{cases} 0 \quad\textrm{if }\lvert z \rvert < 1, \\ 1 \quad\textrm{if }\lvert z \rvert > 2.\end{cases}$$

Clearly partial derivatives are zero, but the function is not constant. In this case, you cannot connect the points $0$ and $2 + 2i$ with a rectangular path (more accurately, a piecewise rectangular path with finite number of steps) lying in $D$, so you cannot use mean value theorem and conclude $f$ at those two points are equal.

On the other hand, if $D$ is open and connected (i.e. a domain), then it is automatically path connected (prove this!), and you would get a rectangular path joining any two points (a slight extension of previous result, proof almost identical).

An obvious generalization of the result thus becomes: if $f' = 0$ on an open subset $\Omega$ of $\mathbb{C}$, then it is constant in each connected component of $\Omega$.